# possible messages in $n$ keystrokes in a language

Tags: combinatorics

The problem statement is "Consider a language whose alphabet has just one letter, but in which words of any length are allowed.
Messages begin and end with words, and when you type a message, you hit the space bar once between words.
How many different messages in this language can be typed using exactly $n$ keystrokes?"

I don't know how to solve this problem. Initially, what I did is:

You can imagine that only letter $0$ and space $1$. So the problem can be translated into how many possible configurations are possible at $n$ keystrokes with $0$'s and $1$'s with no $2$  $1$'s adjacent to each other. Like $001010010$ is valid but $001100010$ is invalid. Also, $1$ can not be in the starting and end of the string here. So solving this problem I first choose the number of $1$'s and then found all combinations. And then added that for each possible number of spaces/$1$'s. I also noticed that in this criteria,(not sure $100\%$) that there can be at most $\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil$ $1$' at $n$ keystrokes. So my answer seems to be $\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil} k\binom{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil}{k}$. This might be wrong.

How can I solve this? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A valid message of length $n\ge 3$ is either (i) a valid message of length $n-1$ with $0$ appended, or (ii) a valid message of length $n-2$ with $10$ appended. So if $u_n$ is the number of valid messages of length $n$, we have:

$u_1=u_2=1$; and $u_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n-2}$ for $n\ge 3$

In other words, the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

(Perhaps you would have spotted this yourself if you had worked out the first few terms.)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1 - The message must start with '0'. Delete the first character, so that you can work with  messages that start with any character

2 - Notice that all possible messages are all the combinations of characters '0' and strings '10'. The number of '10's is exactly the number of '1's

3 - count how many words with $k$ '1's there are, and sum over all possibles $k$

Comment: well how come the message must start with 1, hence start with space? At starting, wouldn't spaces be ignored?

Comment: @funbiggun sorry, I inverted 1 and 0

Comment: @funbiggun corrected now